# How to divide dates based on given two dates

Tags: java, database, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have one scenario, where I have to update the record record, If the record is present in database with the effective and expire date splits logic.

For example the below record is already available in Database.

```
Item  tax   effectiveStartDate   effectiveEndDate
1      5%   17-04-2017           31-12-2047
```

Now I want to update the record with the given effective start date and tax percentage.

For example I have given two dates with 6% of tax then I need to update the record if it is present. The following are the inputs:

```
effective start date: 17-04-2017;
effective end date: 31-12-2047`;

 item : 1
 tax  : 6 %
```

Now record is already present, now what I want is , I have to adjust effective date and expire dates,  20-05-2017 and 31-12-2019.the output of should be like the following:

```
Item  tax   effectiveStartDate   effectiveEndDate
1      5%   17-04-2017           19-05-2017
1      6%   20-05-2017           31-12-2047
```

If again I have given some other dates it should be adjusted like above. In my POC I am using spring MVC with JDBC template I am using. Can someone help me on this logic?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: If I understand you right, you have the one record, you then have to effectuate a change in tax rate to 6% as of May 20, 2017? Which means update the current record to have an expiration date of May 19, 2017, and inserting a new record. What is the problem you have? How to read current record? How to update it? How to insert new record? How to compare dates? How to subtract one day from a date? What? They all seem pretty simple operations, and can each be found by searching the web, so what is you *specific* problem? Show us the code you have so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: The problem is with update , when there are more records in db, which are all need to be updated, I really did not get logic how to handle.  For example now there are already 2 records present then I am giving another tax value 8% with another effective date 18-05-2017 and expire date is like 21-12-2017 that time I feel its difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, if you get other tax value (10% f.e.) to Item 1, you will have to update all entries in the database, isn't it?

If that's the problem, try getting all of them in a List and doing something like:

```
//get all from DB

for(YourObject obj : List){
    if(obj.effectiveFinalDate<newObject.effectiveStartDate){
        obj.effectiveFinalDate = newObject.effectiveStartDate;
    }
    if(obj.effectiveStartDate>newObject.effectiveFinalDate){
        obj.effectiveStartDate = newObject.effectiveFinalDate;
    }
}

//persist all
```

I am not sure at all about what do you want exactly, but I guess it will be something similar to this

EDIT: if you want to set dates to a day more or less, look documentation, it depends on what Object you use as date